# Does Verizon laying fios in DC automatically grant them an easement?

Tags: united-states, easement, district-of-columbia

In general, I wanted to know what rights are granted to Verizon has when they come lay their FioS personal or business service wires.

What are applicable city laws (specifically for District of Columbia), Federal Law, etc. that address whether you automatically grant Verizon easement when they connect the wires?

Comment: There is almost always a utility easement... Also verify your property lines, typically the grassy area between the street and your sidewalk is not part of your property.

Comment: If there isn't an easement a utility has a right to condemn one.

Comment: FWIW, Verizon wants to replace the old copper wires that is already there with fiber optic anyways. So it's not likely they are seeking a new easement. You will have to switch to a FIOS capable box to get regular phone service with them.